# Arabic Text in Json Request is not getting posted

Tags: c#, json, encoding, request, arabic

am facing an issue while posting Arabic text in one of the fields of Json Request. Getting the Error: The Request was Aborted; The Request was cancelled. I tried all the Encoding (UTF8, ASCII, HTMLEncode, JavaScritpEncode and Json Encode) at field level and also entire content level. Actually, it is working perfectly via Soap UI but it is failing from C# client.

I tried different type encodings but with no luck. am expecting a solution from guys who faced similar problems.

Comment: JSON is UTF8 and has no problem representing any character. No extra encoding is needed. Post your code and the actual error response. That's why I can post `Αυτό Εδώ` knowing it will appear just fine

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: C# strings are Unicode, JSON is Unicode, JSON.NET and System.Text.Json use Unicode. StackOverflow itself is a .NET application storing text in Unicode (nvarchar) fields. None of these requires any special encoding. You'll find a *lot* of SO questions containing Arabic, Greek, Chinese text without requiring any special encoding. ` I tried all the Encoding` this will only *cause* problems, precisely because no encoding is needed

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve].  See [ask].  Possibly there is a bug on the server side?  Or possibly the string is not what you think it because your IDE is rendering it [right-to-left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_script)?

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the content length which should be calculated after applying the encoding. I faced similar issue while dealing Non English characters in Json Request